# Uniqueness of adjoint operator in Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm trying to show that the adjoint operator of $A \in \mathcal{B}(X, Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces is uniquely defined as $A^*: Y^* \rightarrow X^*$ and $\forall x \in X, \quad \forall \mu \in Y^{*}, \quad\langle A x, \mu\rangle=\left\langle x, A^{*} \mu\right\rangle$. My attempt so far is:

Suppose $A^*$ is not unique and $B^*:Y^* \to X^*$ that $\mu(Ax)=(B^*\mu)(x)$. Then $\left(A^{*} \mu\right)(x)=(B^*\mu)(x)$ and thus $A^{*}(\mu(x))-B^{*}(\mu(x))=0$. Hence $\left(A^{*}-B^{*}\right) \mu(x)=0$. For $\mu \neq 0$, $B^*=A^*$. How about  $\mu =0$?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You get $(A^{*}\mu ) (x)=(B^{*}\mu ) (x)$ for all $x$ so $A^{*}\mu =B^{*}\mu $. This is true for every $\mu \in Y^{*}$ so $A^{*}=B^{*}$.

Note: $A^{*} (\mu (x))$ does not even make sense.  You should write it as $(A^{*}\mu) (x)$.